# Removing workspace objects whose name start by a pattern using R

Tags: r, object, workspace

I often create temporary objects whose names start by 'tp_' and use user-defined function. In order to keep a clean workspace, I would like to create a function that removes temporary files while keeping user-defined functions.

So far, my code is:

```
rm(list = setdiff(ls(), lsf.str())) # Removes all objects except functions
rm(list = ls(, pattern = "tp_")) # Removes all objects whose name contain 'tp_'
```

I want to:

1. Improve the second function so that is removes objects whose name **start** by 'tp_' (so far, it removes objects whose name **contains** 'tp_'). I've tried `substr(ls(), 1, 3)` but somehow cannot integrate it to my function.
2. Combine these two functions into one.

Some R objects:

```
tp_A = 1
myfun = function(x){sum(x)}
atp_b = 3
```

The function should remove only `tp_A` from the workspace.

Comment: `rm(list=ls(pattern="^tp_"))`

Comment: To expand on A. Webb's comment, you can use regular expression matching in `pattern`.  The `^` forces the regular expression to begin at the start of the string

Comment: Building on A. Webb's answer, the correct expression would be `rm(list = setdiff(ls(, pattern = "^tp_"), lsf.str()))`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The pattern argument uses regular expressions. You can use a caret `^` to match the beginning of the string:

```
rm(list=ls(pattern="^tp_"))
rm(list=setdiff(ls(pattern = "^tp_"), lsf.str()))
```

However, there are other patterns for managing temporary items / keeping clean workspaces than name prefixes.

Consider, for example,

```
temp<-new.env()
temp$x <- 1
temp$y <- 2
with(temp,x+y)
#> 3
rm(temp)
```

Another possibility is `attach(NULL,name="temp")` with `assign`.

Comment: I did not think of the `new.env()` command to manage temporary files. It seems to be a good option!

Comment: Very useful, thanks!